# What is the difference between jdk 8 for arm and java SE embedded

Tags: java

java JDK 8 for arm and java SE embedded both are mainly developed to develop
 the applications in embedded systems.

what is the exact difference between these both JDK??

Answer (score 3):

You can find the difference [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-arm-downloads-2187472.html)

> The JDK includes a Java runtime environment (JRE) for ARM platforms
>   and tools such as the compilers and debuggers necessary for developing
>   applications. Java SE Embedded is a subset of the JDK and includes
>   only the JREs.

JDK 8 for ARM includes tools for developing application for the ARM Platforms and Java SE Embedded includes the runtime only.

Answer (score 1):

As the Oracle site says:

> Java SE Embedded derives from JDK, but provides specific features and support for the embedded market on a limited set of supported platforms. The embedded-specific features and support include additional platforms, small footprint JREs (optional files removed), headless configurations, and memory optimizations.

Source [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/emb7u71-relnotes-2296184.html). This [FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/embedded/embedded-se/documentation/javase-embedded-faq-2043259.html) might be interesting too.